# Step into method proxied by Castle

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, castle-windsor, step-into

I use Castle Windsor in my project. When I try to “step into” a method on a proxied class, Visual Studio steps into some Castle methods (with the “No Source Available” window). I realize this is what actually happens, and I want it to happen this way, but I want to hide this fact during debugging. So when I step into my method, I want Visual Studio to show me the code of my method. Is this possible?

I tried to set it so that symbols for Castle's assemblies aren't loaded, but that just skipped over the method completely.

Comment: Can't you just set a breakpoint in the code you want to hit? That normally works for me in that scenario.

Comment: Yeah, that works, but it's quite tedious to do it every time: 1. open the target method 2. set breakpoint 3. hit F5 to jump to that method 4. unset breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't [just my code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx) debugging work for you?

Comment: It doesn't here, because I have the pdb files for Castle assemblies (and they are in a repository, so I can't easily delete them).  Because of that, VS thinks it is my code. I think.